# How to set timeout for IWbemLocator::ConnectServer?

Tags: visual-c++, wmi

Now I am writing a WMI query utility following the examples provided in this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390422(v=vs.85).aspx

But I find that the program may blocking on the call to IWbemLocator::ConnectServer. Here is the code:

```
  hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
    _bstr_t(L"\\\\COMPUTERNAME\\root\\cimv2"),
    _bstr_t(useToken?NULL:pszName),    // User name
    _bstr_t(useToken?NULL:pszPwd),     // User password
    NULL,                              // Locale             
    NULL,                              // Security flags
    _bstr_t(useNTLM?NULL:pszAuthority),// Authority        
    NULL,                              // Context object 
    &pSvc                              // IWbemServices proxy
    );
```

My question is how can I set a time out option, before calling  `IWbemLocator::ConnectServer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [`ConnectServer` method description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa391769.aspx), setting the *lSecurityFlags* parameter to `WBEM_FLAG_CONNECT_USE_MAX_WAIT` enforces a 2 minute timeout. Looks like there's no way to set a custom timeout though.